# Group representation definition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm struggling to understand a passage of definition in group representation on Pierre Ramond's book "Group Theory: A physicist's surveys".[image]

My doubt is in this definition of (3.6). I can understand that 3.5 is about homomorphism, but about 3.6 I could not figure out.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas (3.5) and (3.6) together rephrase the fact that
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \mathcal{M}^{[1]}(gg') & 0 \\ \mathcal{N}(gg') & \mathcal{M}^{[\perp]}(gg') \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathcal{M}^{[1]}(g) & 0 \\ \mathcal{N}(g) & \mathcal{M}^{[\perp]}(g) \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mathcal{M}^{[1]}(g') & 0 \\ \mathcal{N}(g') & \mathcal{M}^{[\perp]}(g') \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I just realized it before coming here haha but thank you anyway.